# MySQL MAX(date) in LEFT JOIN ON 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
Product 
   Id
Sale
   Id
   Date
SaleDetails
   Id
   IdSale
   IdProduct
   QTE
```

**Product**

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P1 |
| 2 | P2 |
| 3 | P3 |
| 4 | P4 |

**Sale**

| Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210801 |
| 2 | 20210802 |
| 3 | 20210803 |

**SaleDetails**

| Id | IdSale | IdProduct | Qte |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 11 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 12 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 13 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 14 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 15 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 | 16 |
| 8 | 1 | 2 | 17 |
| 9 | 3 | 4 | 18 |
| 10 | 3 | 4 | 19 |

I need to get the `SaleDetail.Qte` and `Sale.date` where (`Sale.Date` is the latest AND `SaleDetail.Id` is the biggest (can be 2 `SaleDetail.IdProduct` with the same `SaleDetail.IdSale` )) for each `Product` using a LEFT JOIN.

The expected result would be:

| IdProduct | Qte | SaleDetail.Id | IdSale | Sale.Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 2 | 2 | 20210802 |
| 2 | 13 | 4 | 2 | 20210802 |
| 3 | Null | Null | Null | Null |
| 4 | 19 | 10 | 3 | 20210803 |

I've been trying something like this without much success

```
SELECT 
    Product.id,
    S.QteS,
    S.DateS
FROM 
    Product
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            SaleDetails.IdProduct,
            SaleDetails.Qte AS QteS,
            MAX(Sale.date) As DateS
        FROM 
            SaleDetails
        JOIN
            Sale
        ON 
            Sale.id = SaleDetails.IdSale
        GROUP BY 
            Sale.date
        ORDER BY 
            Sale.id DESC
    ) S 
    ON S.IdProduct= Product.Id
GROUP BY Product.Id
ORDER BY Product.Id
```

Comment: better you can provide few data of each table and expected output.

Comment: Done can you please check again?

Comment: which version of mysql you use?

Comment: 5.6 i can upgrade if needed

Comment: version 5.8 is better for using many update things like ROW_NUMBER(). I'm using latest version (5.8). If any product has no sales info then this product will come or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all product info needed so LEFT JOIN is used. But All sales info related product is needed then INNER JOIN would be better choice. As latest version of MYSQL is used so ranking function is applied here.

Here consider latest sale id and latest saledetailid wise product info

```
-- MySQL(v5.8)
SELECT p.id idProduct
     , t.qte
     , t.saleDetailId
     , t.idSale
     , t.tdate
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sd.idProduct, sd.qte
                , sd.id saleDetailId
                , sd.idSale, s.tdate
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sd.idProduct ORDER BY s.tdate DESC, sd.id DESC) row_num
          FROM Sale s
          INNER JOIN SaleDetails sd
                  ON s.id = sd.idSale) t
       ON p.id = t.idProduct
      AND t.row_num = 1;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92cd6557716f6e7c72000f34004b07f6

Here consider product wise max saleid then retrieve product info as per latest sale detail id

```
-- MySQL(v5.8)
SELECT p.id idProduct
     , t.qte
     , t.saleDetailId
     , t.idSale
     , t.tdate
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sd.idProduct
                , sd.qte
                , sd.id saleDetailId
                , sd.idSale
                , s.tdate
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sd.idSale, sd.idProduct ORDER BY sd.id DESC) row_num
           FROM SaleDetails sd
           INNER JOIN (SELECT idProduct
                            , MAX(idSale) idSale
                       FROM SaleDetails
                       GROUP BY idProduct) td
                   ON sd.idProduct = td.idProduct
                  AND sd.idSale = td.idSale
           INNER JOIN Sale s
                   ON s.id = sd.idSale) t
       ON p.id = t.idProduct
      AND t.row_num = 1;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=afd3a030e49a57cbad0bf34dd79d4f69

At this case disable OR tmp.idProduct IS NULL from WHERE clause where all sales related product need.

```
-- MySQL (v5.8)
SELECT tmp.saleDetailId
     , tmp.idSale
     , p.id idProduct
     , tmp.qte, tmp.tdate
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sd.id saleDetailId
                , sd.idSale, idProduct
                , sd.qte, s.tdate
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sd.idProduct ORDER BY sd.id DESC) row_numm
           FROM (SELECT *
                      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tdate DESC) row_num
                 FROM Sale) s
           INNER JOIN SaleDetails sd
                   ON s.id = sd.idSale
                  AND s.row_num = 1) tmp
       ON p.id = tmp.idProduct
WHERE tmp.row_numm = 1 OR tmp.idProduct IS NULL;
```

Please check this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99a4f431df3d6567b90adb269605cf2f

Alternate way to ROW_NUMBER() which supports lower version of MySQL

```
-- MySQL(v5.6)
SELECT tmp.saleDetailsdid, tmp.idSale
     , p.id idProduct, tmp.qte, tmp.tdate
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT @row_no := IF(@prev_val = t.idProduct, @row_no + 1, 1) AS row_number
                , @prev_val := t.idProduct AS idProduct
                , t.saleDetailsdid, t.idSale, t.tdate, t.qte
           FROM (SELECT sd.id saleDetailsdid, sd.idSale
                     , sd.idProduct, s.tdate, sd.qte
                FROM (SELECT id, tdate
                           , (@row_number:=  @row_number + 1) row_num
                      FROM Sale, (SELECT @row_number := 0) x 
                      ORDER BY row_num DESC LIMIT 1) s
           INNER JOIN SaleDetails sd
                  ON s.id = sd.idSale) t,
           (SELECT @row_no := 0) x,
           (SELECT @prev_val := 0) y
           ORDER BY t.idProduct, t.saleDetailsdid DESC) tmp
      ON p.id = tmp.idProduct
WHERE tmp.row_number = 1;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ca912073ea4fc522dc63be3f7fdb012e

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help i'll upgrade my MySQL version and try this

Comment: welcome @AMT for your response. Please let me know if my query is helped you or not.

Comment: Hi @AMT please check now. Provide version wise query.

Comment: I still want to get Product.Id even if there is no sale

Comment: i tried it in a large database, it gives wrong results

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=422d5729e5a456d9c87007df22ae737b

Comment: Please check my query and I added an extra product that so that null value comes https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3472af8892d8b368adf621b10a3ebf88

Comment: @AMT I've written query according to your table structure and sample data. If it's shows wrong result then please provide exact data as a sample.

Comment: Hi @Rahul, i'm not familiar yet with PARTITION BY function, but when added some it looks that it's not working, please check this thanks again for your priceless help.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8fb078c2a26758fefa00da7e21abd778

Comment: @AMT PARTITION BY is working properly. According to your data last saledate is 2021-08-03 where saleid is 3 and product id = 4. So at this combination max sale details id is 19. Thats why it shows value and other 3 remaining product is NULL. If you don't show null value then remove OR tmp.idProduct IS NULL from where clause and use INNER JOIN. Or any new business logic which you forgot to mention please explain.

Comment: The problem is that it shows data only for the last date, what i need to get is for every Product, the last Sale with SaleDetail
So the output should the combination of the last query and the previous one
For P1, IdSale = 2 + SaleDetails
For P2, IdSale = 2 + SaleDetails
For P3, IdSale = Null + Null
For P4, IdSale = 3 + SaleDetails

Comment: As per your question I think you need all sales date data with max saledetailid and productid. Please provide sample data as per your need. Otherwise it's very difficult to answer. Please update your sample data and expected result in question section.

Comment: I Just updated my sample data, really sorry that i didn't explain my self well.
Can you please check again?

Comment: If saledate = 20210801 and existing value for product P3 then? do you need product wise max sale date?

Comment: actually yes, i need max date from sale and qte from details for each product if exists.

Comment: @AMT please check now.

Comment: That worked like a charm.
I can't thank you enough for you time and you patience.

Comment: welcome @AMT for accepting it and happy to know it helps you. Also give a upvote along with accepted if possible.

Comment: i would've done that with a great pleasure, but it was my first time here, i don't have the rank yet to vote.

Comment: Can i bother you again @Rahul ? i'm trying to understand your query and i think i figured it out.
You make the assumption that the MAX(id) in Sale is the one with the last date, so what if that was not the case as in this example.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=06591af4f3e03f384b7ecf1caa6aef18
P1 and P2 should be displaying Sale Id = 1 not Id = 2

Comment: Please check it https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92cd6557716f6e7c72000f34004b07f6

Comment: Ranking function is amazing, this is exactly what i was trying to do in my first query without using ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: it is just perfect.
your're a life saver.